# Issues with embedding web links

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a string in vba which has a web link. However, when the string is displayed on the Microsoft word page. The text gets wrapped and the link is broken. How can I ensure that VBA knows where the link starts and stops?

string looks like this:

```
Dim My_MSG As String 
My_MSG = "Full company list can be found at finance.yahoo.com/blogs/hot-stock-minute/… by yahoo' by yourclients."
```

when this string is populated in a word table it the link dose not recognize the complete link

Comment: Can you share the string? and how are you using vba to write that string

Comment: my_msg =" text....link..text..."

Comment: Could you please be more elaborate in explaing? Perhaps you could amend your question to show us the exact code + Weblink that you are using?

Comment: Dim My_MSG As String
    My__MSG = "Full company list can be found at   http://finance.yahoo.com/blogs/hot-stock-minute/learning-earnings-pfizer-aetna-jetblue-apple-trades-flat-125257972.html by yahoo' by yourclients."

Comment: the string puts text in a word table which wraps text and breaks the link

Comment: Please re-read my last comment... especially this part... `Perhaps you could amend your question...`

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that is that code not enough

Comment: No because of two reasons. `1` Comments are not supposed to be used to share codes. Please amend the question to provide full data `2` The comment has converted the link to an hyperlink. It's very difficult to read codes in comments.

Comment: Are you sure that is the correct link? It seems like you just copied it from the comment and pasted it in the question.

Comment: i tried putting any link in there it breaks because of the length. I am looking for something like I a href property for html

Comment: Let it break. Copy the code from your vba editor and put it in the above question :) If need be i will fix it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Word won't recognize a link automatically. You can use Hyperlinks.Add to insert a hyperlink. Here's an example.

```
Sub AddTextwHyperlink()
   Dim objDoc As Document
   Dim objRng As Range

   Set objDoc = ActiveDocument
   Set objRng = Selection.Range

   'Adds text before link.
   objRng.InsertAfter "Full company list can be found at "

   'Collapses range so that hyperlink will be added after text.
   objRng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd

   'Adds hyperlink and sets the range to start after the hyperlinked text.
   objRng.start = objDoc.Hyperlinks.Add(Anchor:=objRng, Address:="http://finance.yahoo.com/blogs/hot-stock-minute/").Range.End

   'Adds the rest of the text.
   objRng.InsertAfter " by yahoo' by yourclients."

End Sub
```